# For JSON Query error

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to use the 'For JSON PATH'/'For JSON AUTO' in my query to see the output and I am geetting 'Incorrect syntax near JSON' error. Below is my code:

```
    SELECT TOP 5   
       recid As Id,  
       FirstName, LastName,  
       status As 'Info.status',  
       state As 'Info.state'  
   FROM dbo.Consumers
   FOR JSON PATH
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `SELECT @@version`

Comment: Write this in SSMS and share what returns: SELECT @@VERSION. If it does not say SQL Server 2016 or greater, the JSON command will never work.

Comment: `FOR JSON` is supported in SQL Server 2016+. Not 2014 (or prior).

Comment: Thanks. I can check this

Comment: [JSON data in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server) for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON in SQL Server is only supported in versions 2016 and later. Your installation is a 2014 install so it will not work. You can either upgrade your installation to SQL Server 2016 or look up custom JSON solutions/functions/procs that others have written.

Answer (score 0):

For people who stick firmly with SQL server 2014 without/possibility for not updating to next version, below solution can be used to output SQL select values into JSON format. This is not straight forward method because they first convert the output to XML and then structure the output to JSON format. Which may be painful if we have 100 fields to select from a table.

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/how-to-get-output-sql-server-as-a-json-string/

So the answer would be to update SQl server version to 2016 and higher for this functionality to work